# How to Align Label and Select Boxes Inside Angular Form

Tags: html, css, angular-forms

I'm trying to align the select drop-down boxes that are inside the angular form while keeping the labels to the left and the whole form centered.

I've already spent more time than I should trying to google how to do this and after many attempts it always seems to looks worse than how I originally had it.

```
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <p>Please select the office location, data, and time you would like to have your appointment.</p>
  </div>
  <form class="form" [formGroup]="appointmentForm">
      <label for="office">Office:&nbsp;</label>
      <select id="office" class="form-control selectTag" [(ngModel)]="applicant.appointment[0].office" formControlName="office">
        <option *ngFor="let office of offices; let i = index" [value]="offices[i].office">
          {{offices[i].office}}
        </option>
      </select>

      <label for="month">Month:&nbsp;</label>
      <select id="month" class="form-control selectTag" [(ngModel)]="applicant.appointment[0].month" formControlName="month">
        <option *ngFor="let month of months; let i = index" [value]="months[i].month">
          {{months[i].month}}
        </option>
      </select>

      <label for="date">Date:&nbsp;</label>
      <select id="date" class="form-control selectTag" [(ngModel)]="applicant.appointment[0].date" formControlName="date">
        <option *ngFor="let date of dates; let i = index" [value]="dates[i].date">
          {{dates[i].date}}
        </option>
      </select>

      <label for="time">Time:&nbsp;</label>
      <select id="time" class="form-control selectTag" [(ngModel)]="applicant.appointment[0].time" formControlName="time">
        <option *ngFor="let time of times; let i = index" [value]="times[i].time">
          {{times[i].time}}
        </option>
      </select>
  </form>
</body>
```

```
/* Organized in alphabetical order */
body {
  padding-bottom: 65px;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

label {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-left: 40%;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

select {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  align-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-block` on the `label` instead of `float: left;`.

Instead of setting a `margin-left` on the `label` element to achieve the centering of the form, you can add a defined width for the whole `form` element, and center it with `margin: 0 auto;`.

```css
/* Organized in alphabetical order */
body {
  padding-bottom: 65px;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

select {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  align-content: center;
}

ul {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

form {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <p>Please select the office location, data, and time you would like to have your appointment.</p>
  </div>
  <form class="form" [formGroup]="appointmentForm">
      <label for="office">Office:&nbsp;</label>
      <select id="office" class="form-control selectTag" [(ngModel)]="applicant.appointment[0].office" formControlName="office">
        <option *ngFor="let office of offices; let i = index" [value]="offices[i].office">
          {{offices[i].office}}
        </option>
      </select>

      <label for="month">Month:&nbsp;</label>
      <select id="month" class="form-control selectTag" [(ngModel)]="applicant.appointment[0].month" formControlName="month">
        <option *ngFor="let month of months; let i = index" [value]="months[i].month">
          {{months[i].month}}
        </option>
      </select>

      <label for="date">Date:&nbsp;</label>
      <select id="date" class="form-control selectTag" [(ngModel)]="applicant.appointment[0].date" formControlName="date">
        <option *ngFor="let date of dates; let i = index" [value]="dates[i].date">
          {{dates[i].date}}
        </option>
      </select>

      <label for="time">Time:&nbsp;</label>
      <select id="time" class="form-control selectTag" [(ngModel)]="applicant.appointment[0].time" formControlName="time">
        <option *ngFor="let time of times; let i = index" [value]="times[i].time">
          {{times[i].time}}
        </option>
      </select>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: that did align the select boxes but then they were all places on the left side of the screen and the labels stayed in the middle of the screen. I have the float: left there so that the labels will appear to the left of the boxes

Comment: @nick_eagles See my updated answer— I added a fix for centering the form, too.

Comment: It's looking better but now the labels are appearing above each of the boxes. Is it possible to have them lined up to the left of each of them? Like how they were originally

Comment: @nick_eagles If you click the "Run code snippet" button in my answer, you'll see the labels lined up with the select boxes as desired. In the code you're working with, is the `display: inline-block` property set for `label`? If so, are there any differences between the code you're working with and what you posted here that may be causing the alignment issue? Possibly you have additional style and need to set the `width` property on the `form` higher than `300px` to accommodate both elements in one row.

Comment: I did run that code snippet and it just looked like it did when I first posted the question so I'm a little confused as to why that didn't change, and I've also played around with the width of the form but that make the label position change. It still stays above the select boxes. I've even tried copying the code you posted